# EditText in dialog android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog, layoutparams

i have made a edittext in a dialog but i cant get to change the height.

```
AlertDialog.Builder editalert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

editalert.setTitle("messagetitle");
editalert.setMessage("here is the message");


final EditText input = new EditText(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
input.setLayoutParams(lp);
editalert.setView(input);

editalert.setPositiveButton("Send via email", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {


    }
});


editalert.show();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
edittext.setHeight(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it`s too late, but you can try this.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```