# Giving password protection to Android Settings

Tags: android, passwords

I am using android settings inside my app(Launcher), so i can able to set a password protection, but far from that some tabs/device can able to access settings in different methods, so i am trying to create a password protection to the whole"**system(Device)settings**", how i can do it, is it possible ,
From my search i found this [Android, Detect when other apps are launched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched) 
Can any one tell me how it works..
And it says that will not work from JellyBean and above. READ_LOGS permission is now reserved for system apps only, Is there any way for JellyBean.

Comment: Before accessing the settings, you can create a Dialog with a field for the password to be filled, like this thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871150/edittext-in-dialog-android

Comment: I wish to  create a password protection to the whole system settings...

Comment: If by "System Settings" you mean the "settings" of your application, I think that the Dialog can fin into that requirement. Just show it and if the entered password is correct, visualize the "Settings", if not - then nothing happens or an error message appears, like aToast or something.

Comment: I mean the device settings ..How i can able to know that i am accessing device settings

Comment: You're password protecting the Android Settings, which are built into the phone itself ? It's not an app you can prevent the access to. I think that this isn't allowed, for security reasons ..

Answer (score 0):

If the solution proposed in the comment is ok with you, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584063/adding-edittext-to-alert-dialog) I found this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyFeedActivity.this);
        LayoutInflater inflater=MyFeedActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
        //this is what I did to added the layout to the alert dialog
        View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog,null);       
        alert.setView(layout);
        final EditText usernameInput=(EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.dialogusername);
        final EditText passwordInput=(EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.dialogpassword);
```

I hope it will fit your needs.

Comment: I know this but i am trying to  create a password protection to the whole system settings

Comment: @Sree i am also facing same problem have you got the answer for this - to protect device settings

Comment: @ask4solutions yes i managed that some how, but i am sorry i really forgot what i did.. bez it is long back